# Assign single template to multiple custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, templates

I have a number of custom post types that I would like to display with the same template which I have created initially as `single-photography.php` in my theme.

Is there any way to assign this template to multiple custom post types?

I understand I can probably do this within the `single.php` file with a conditional include based on `get_post_type()`, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter `template_include` and pass your custom template as return value depending on your own conditions.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) 
{
    // your custom post types
    $my_types = array( 'photography', 'painting' );
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $my_types ) )
        return $template;

    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-photography.php'; 
});
```